# Optimal Stopping Theorem

Tags: probability, martingales

The usual optimal stopping theorem states the following:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $\{X_n\}$ be a super martingale and $T$ be a stopping time with respect to a filtration $\{\mathcal{B}_n\}$ in $\mathcal{B}.$ Then $E[X_T] \leq E[X_1]$ whenever the following conditions hold:

1) $\Pr\{T < \infty\} = 1.$

2) $\mathbb{E}(|X_T|) < \infty.$

3) $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_m|1_{T > m}) = 0.$

However the following proof 'seems' to indicate that only condition 1 is necessary. I know this proof should be incorrect (as standard examples show), but I am unable to identify the mistake. So kindly help me with the same.

Let $Y_n = X_{n\wedge T}$ $\forall n.$ Clearly, $\{Y_n\}$ is a super martingale. Since $\Pr\{T < \infty\} = 1,$ it also follows that $Y_n \rightarrow X_T$ a.s. Now by monotonicity property, it follows that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left(\bigwedge_{m \geq k}Y_m|\mathcal{B}_1 \right) \leq \mathbb{E}(Y_k|\mathcal{B}_1) \hspace{0.2cm} \forall k
\end{equation}

But because $\{Y_n\}$ is a super martingale, $\mathbb{E}(Y_k|\mathcal{B}_1) \leq Y_1 = X_1\wedge T = X_1$ (since $T\geq 1).$  It thus follows that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left(\bigwedge_{m \geq k}Y_m|\mathcal{B}_1 \right) \leq X_1.
\end{equation}

Now by monotone convergence theorem for conditional expectations,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(X_T|\mathcal{B}_1) = E\left(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\bigwedge_{m \geq k}Y_m|\mathcal{B}_1\right) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}  \left(\bigwedge_{m \geq k}Y_m |\mathcal{B}_1\right) \leq X_1.
\end{equation}

Taking expectations again, we get that

\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{E}(X_T) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_1)
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Hint: you need to ensure that $E(\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\ \ \ )=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}E(\ \ \ )$.

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem might not apply in this case. You've said nothing pertaining to the sign of $X_n$, and so it's possible that the sequence $\wedge_{m \geq k} Y_m$ is negative in some places, hence MCT is generally false. On the other hand, if $X_n$ is a nonnegative supermartingale, can you see why $X_1$ integrable implies the uniform integrability of $Y_n = X_{n \wedge T}$?

Comment: Ahh! How stupid of me! Thank you.